# Add href behavior on a div

Tags: html, window, href

I have a div and add some click capabilities on it
like

```
<div id="myDiv" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.location.href='http://www.google.com'" >
press here
</div>
```

Click works but i want to add on right click on this div something similar to a regular href.
I mean the option Open in New Window.
Can be possible?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know what are you seeking for, but I have added answer, according what I know

Comment: when you right click on a link (a href) you have a menu with some options, one of that is Open Link in New Tab. This works for a href but not for a div with onclick capability. I want to know if is possible to have the same option right clicking on a div. Now is much clear? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<a>` instead of `<div>`:

```
<a id="myDiv" style="cursor:pointer" href="http://www.google.com">
press here
</a>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Loomrmrm/

To directly open in new window do this:

```
<a id="myDiv" style="cursor:pointer" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
press here
</a>
```

Comment: No, i need to be a div ... i know that a will do the job

Answer (score 0):

when I test it that works... But to make it simpler just do this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"_blank">Press Here</a>
```

The attribute _blank" after the link makes it open in a new tab. But when typing the link make sure that the link has the http:// before and the / after.

Comment: I should use div, not a

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `div` inside an `anchor`

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="myDiv" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.location.href='http://www.google.com'" >
    press here
</div>
</a>
```

But

Answer (score 0):

Here the full code, u have to style everything to let it look cool:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <div id="myDiv" style"cursor:pointer" onclick="" oncontextmenu="openMyContext();return false;">
    press here
    </div>

<div id="myContext" style="display: none; position: absolute;" onmouseout="onOut();">
 <p>Option 1</p>
</div>

<script>

function openMyContext(){
var e = window.event;
   document.getElementById('myContext').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('myContext').style.left = e.pageX-5 + "px";
   document.getElementById('myContext').style.top = e.pageY-15 + "px";

}

function onOut(){
  document.getElementById('myContext').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```